# Too few arguments to function ReadingData::__construct(), 1 passed in ... KernelDevDebugContainer.php on and exactly 2 expected

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I created a Service to read data from the database.
In order to achieve that, I want to make a Controller and throw this controller I want to call first the `ReadingDataService`.

**Error Message:**

> **Too few arguments** to function `TryPlugin\Service\ReadingData::__construct()`, **1 passed** in `/var/www/html/var/cache/dev_he0523cc28be2f689acaab5c325675d68/ContainerFt0wDoq/Shopware_Production_KernelDevDebugContainer.php` on line 25455 and **exactly 2 expected**

**Code:**
**ReadingData.php**

```php
class ReadingData
{
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;
    private Context $con;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository, Context $con)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function readData(): void
    {
        $criteria1 = new Criteria();
        $products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria1, $this->con)->getEntities();

    }

}
```

**PageController.php**

```php
/**
 * @RouteScope (scopes={"storefront"})
 */
class PageController extends StorefrontController
{
    
    /**
     * @Route("/examples", name="examples", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function showExample(ReadingData $ReadingDatan): Response
    {
        $meinData = $ReadingDatan->readData();
        return $this->renderStorefront('@Storefront/storefront/page/content/index.html.twig', [
            'products' => $meinData,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Service.xml:**

```xml
<service id="TryPlugin\Service\ReadingData">
    <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
</service>

<!--ReadingDate From Controller-->
<service id="TryPlugin\Storefront\Controller\PageController" public="true">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </call>
    <tag name="controller.service_arguments"/>
</service>
```

Comment: Don't mean to sound overly snarky but if your constructor expects two arguments and you only pass one then is it really that hard to see the problem?

Comment: @Cerad I think @Samee is trying to autowire the `Shopware\Core\Framework\Context` as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.matheusgontijo.com/2022/01/26/what-is-context-in-shopware-6). Still trying to figure out why it's not working though.

Comment: @ChrisHappy Samee is not using autowire but rather manual service definitions.  This is their second question on this topic.  It might actually simplify things if they did use autowire but I don't think they really know how to configure it.  And if they do it wrong then it will just create more problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to pass the 2nd argument in `service.xml`

Your class requires two arguments:

```php
public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository, Context $con) { //...
```

but only provides one in `service.xml`:

```xml
<service id="TryPlugin\Service\ReadingData">
    <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
    <!-- Need argument for `Context $con` -->
</service>
```

Looking at the documentation, `Context` does not appear to be [autowired](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) by default.

Therefore, you must [inject the service](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/dependency-injection) yourself in `service.xml`.

If you grow tired of all ways specifying the arguments in `service.xml`, look into enabling and configuring [autowire for ShopWare](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is unecessary in the first place.

Do the following in your controller and pass the context down:

```
namespace TryPlugin\Storefront\Controller;


use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\LoginRequired;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\RouteScope;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use TryPlugin\Service\ReadingData;


/**
 * @RouteScope (scopes={"storefront"})
 */
class PageController extends StorefrontController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/examples", name="examples", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function showExample(ReadingData $ReadingDatan, Context $context): Response
    {
        $meinData = $ReadingDatan->readData($context);
        return $this->renderStorefront('@Storefront/storefront/page/content/index.html.twig', [
            'products' => $meinData,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This will work since there is a parameter resolver for controllers.